# При инициализации нескольких родительских классов один из конструкторов не вызывается

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, инициализация, множественное-наследование

Пытаюсь инициализировать родительские классы, но в конструктор класса A даже не заходит.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        print("A enter")
        print("A leave")


class B(list, A):
    def __init__(self, arg, *content, **kwargs):
        print("B enter")
        super(B, self).__init__(arg=arg, *content, **kwargs)
        print("B leave")
```

На выходе получаю:

```
B enter
B leave
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы родительский класс A инициализировался аргументами arg и **kwargs, а класс list аргументом *content

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе ? И покажите как вы создаете экземпляры классов.

Comment: `class B( A, list):`

Comment: @S.Nick B enter -> A enter -> A leave -> B leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        self.arg = arg
        self._dict = kwargs
        print("A enter --->", arg, kwargs)
        print("A leave --->", self._dict)


class B(A, list):
    def __init__(self, arg, *content, **kwargs):
        print("\nB enter")
        super(B, self).__init__(arg=arg, *content, **kwargs)
        print("B leave\n")
        print(arg, content, kwargs)
        print(a.arg, a._dict['name'])
        
a = A('Ky-ky', name = 'Вася', hello = 'world')

b = B('Ok')
```

---

Update

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        self.arg = arg
        self._dict = kwargs
        print("A enter --->", arg, kwargs)
        print("A leave --->", self._dict)


class B(A, list):
    def __init__(self, arg, *content, **kwargs):
        print("\nB enter: ", arg, content, kwargs)
        super(B, self).__init__(arg)
        
        print("B leave\n")
        print(arg, content, kwargs)
        print(a.arg, a._dict['name'])
        
a = A('Ky-ky', name = 'Вася', hello = 'world')

b = B("arg", "content", nonpos1=0, nonpos2=1)
```

---

или так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg, *content, **kwargs):             # + *content
        self.arg = arg
        self._dict = kwargs
        print("A enter --->", arg, kwargs)
        print("A leave --->", self._dict)


class B(A, list):
    def __init__(self, arg, *content, **kwargs):
        print("\nB enter: ", arg, content, kwargs)
        super(B, self).__init__(arg, *content, **kwargs)
        
        print("B leave\n")
        print(arg, content, kwargs)
        print(a.arg, a._dict['name'])
        
a = A('Ky-ky', name = 'Вася', hello = 'world')

b = B("arg", "content", nonpos1=0, nonpos2=1)
```

Comment: При попытке создать экземпляр класса B таким образом: `B("arg", "content", nonpos1=0, nonpos2=1)`. Получаю ошибку: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'arg'`

Comment: @DeWoPrg попробуйте Update

Comment: @DeWoPrg попробуйте Update 2

Comment: @s-nick, в Update в конструктор класса A передается пустое значение kwargs

Comment: @DeWoPrg попробуйте Update 2

Comment: @s-nick, Update 2 работает, но насколько это нормально с точки зрения проектирования?

Comment: @DeWoPrg я не знаю что вы проектируете, а что вас собственно смущает или настораживает ?

Comment: @s-nick, я начал заниматься программированием не так давно (писал немного на C++ и C#, а сейчас в качестве языка для написания небольших штук решил попробовать Python), а раньше такого делать не приходилось, потому и спросил

Comment: @DeWoPrg все нормально, будут трудности - задавайте вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

[Используйте super() чтобы получить родительский класс](https://realpython.com/python-super/#:%7E:text=__init__()%20of%20the%20superclass,directly%20on%20it%3A%20super().)